# SSRS conditional result

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to create a report for prepayments/extra payments before their actual time of payment. how can I tell in query to show the whole row with the extra amount, if the condition is true. example:

IF (Field.A+Field.B)<=(Field.C+Field.D); then skip this row and check the next row; but if (Field.A+Field.B)>(Field.C+Field.D), then show this row with the extra amount in specified cell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the row and set the `Visibility`-`Hidden` property to

```
=(Field.A+Field.B)<=(Field.C+Field.D)
```

Comment: Can you also tell me how to set default value for date picker parameter as =Today() with a specific time? So it is by default on today's date and always considers that time - for today and any other day.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this solved your problem, please indicate this by marking it as the accepted answer (green tick) so that future searchers will know the solution worked. (Up votes are also appreciated).

Comment: I just did. I am new here, and before I only clicked UP arrow and because I don't have enough reputation it didn't update. I didn't notice the green tick.